# How to select dataframe columns in a loop using dict values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create subplots which will plot graphs based on the values of a dictionary. The values themselves are list of variables. However, I'm not sure how can I access dictionary values as the dictionary is already within a for loop. Is there a better way? Maybe use lists of list instead of a dictionary?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [50, 35, 45, 93, 45],
             'cost': [10, 11, 12, 13, 15],
             'inventory': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
             'popularity': [7, 4, 9, 4, 2],
             'supply': [20, 30 , 40, 54, 69],
             'demand': [30, 43, 56, 76, 98]})

some_dict = {'first': ['cost', 'price'],
            'second' : ['inventory', 'popularity', 'supply'],
            'third': ['supply', 'inventory', 'demand']}

fig, axes = plt.subplots(8, 8, figsize = (55, 25))

for x in np.arange(0, 8):
    for y in np.arange(0, 8):
        sns.heatmap(df[some_dict.values()[x+y]].corr(),
            cmap = 'BuPu',
            annot = True, 
            fmt = '0.2f',
            cbar= False,
            ax  = axes[x, y]
           );
```

The code above doesn't work and gives the following error

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `some_dict` represents the combination of columns with which to plot `.corr()` as a `seaborn.heatmap`
- When dealing with multiple `axes`, it is almost always easiest to flatten them into a 1-d array with `.flatten()`
- For the OP, it will be easiest to `enumerate` the `key-value` pairs, and use `i` to index the correct `axes`.

```py
# create an axes for each key in some_dict
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(15, 7))

# flatten the axes array
axes = axes.flatten()

# enumerate and loop through the key-value pairs
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(some_dict.items()):

    # plot the heatmap for the selected columns
    sns.heatmap(data=df[v].corr(), cmap='BuPu', annot=True, 
                fmt='0.2f', cbar= False, ax=axes[i])

    # use the dict key as the axes title
    axes[i].set(title=k)

# delete unused axes
fig.delaxes(axes[3])
    
plt.show()
```

[image]